# Remove public from URL in Laravel 9 using .htaccess on shared hosting/CPanel hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel, shared-hosting, laravel-9

I am trying to host a Laravel 9 application on a Cpanel shared host. However, the application keeps returning the below error even when I try to access `https://example.com/public`. Also below is my .htaccess file at the root; it used to work perfectly with Laravel 8 but is not working anymore. My problem is I want to access my application just using the domain without `/public` or `/public.index.php` (e.g., example.com).

> Internal server error 500

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to check your server's error log for the details of this 500 error. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? (You should have another `.htaccess` file at `/public/.htaccess`. "or `/public.index.php`" - presumably you mean `/public/index.php`?

Answer (score 4):

How to remove public from url in laravel 9

- create a `.htaccess` file in root directory
- Add this code

  ```
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ server.php
  ```
- create `server.php` in the root directory
- Add this code

  ```
  $uri = urldecode(
      parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
  );

  // This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
  // built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
  // application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
  if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
      return false;
  }

  require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
  ```

Comment: I saw several responses here in multiple SO questions... only this one worked for me. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
> ```

You are missing the slash prefix on the *CondPattern* `!^public`, so this *condition* will always be successful and repeatedly rewrite the request, potentially causing a rewrite loop (ie. 500 error).

It should be like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public($|/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

HOWEVER, you should also have another `.htaccess` file with mod_rewrite directives in the `/public` subdirectory that manages the routing through your Laravel app, and this should prevent a rewrite-loop.